# Mysql InnoDB crach

Tags: mysql, database

Mysql craches almost every day and I need to restart MYSQL..
Own VPS 512MB ram, mysql logs :

```
131115 10:03:36 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131115 10:03:36 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131115 10:03:36 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131115 10:03:36 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
131115 10:03:36 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
131115 10:03:36 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131115 10:03:36 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
131115 10:03:36  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this log about shutting down or starting?

I suppose your machine was abnormally shut down which caused damage of logs. So, your db files are inconsistent because of `mysqld` was not stopped gracefully and your log-files (durability records) are inconsistent too because of physical storage damage.

Comment: Yes it crached.. is there a reason for that abnormally shutdown ?

Comment: Maybe it was a hardware malfunction.